# How to add manufacturer logo in featured products module? | Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Hy guys, im preaty new to opencart and i need ur help.
I managed to add the logo of the manufacturer on the product page,but know i want to display the logo of the manufacturer in the featured products.
I managed to add the name of the manufacturer, but dont know how to get the img link of it :(. Im using OC 1.5.5.1

this is my code for `featured.php`:

```php
<?php
class ControllerModuleFeatured extends Controller {
    //alex start
    protected function index($setting) {
        $this->language->load('module/featured'); 

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $this->data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product'); 

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $this->data['products'] = array();

        $products = explode(',', $this->config->get('featured_product'));       

        if (empty($setting['limit'])) {
            $setting['limit'] = 5;
        }

        $products = array_slice($products, 0, (int)$setting['limit']);

        foreach ($products as $product_id) {
            $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

            if ($product_info) {
                if ($product_info['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $setting['image_width'], $setting['image_height']);
                } else {
                    $image = false;
                }

                if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = $product_info['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }

                $this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'      => $product_info['product_id'],
                    'thumb'           => $image,
                    'name'            => $product_info['name'],
                    'manufacturer'    => $product_info['manufacturer'],              
                    'manufacturer_id' => $product_info['manufacturer_id'],
                    //'manufacturer_img'=> $product_info['manufacturer_img'],
                    'manufacturers'   => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $product_info['manufacturer_id']),
                    'price'           => $price,
                    'special'         => $special,
                    'rating'          => $rating,
                    'reviews'         => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$product_info['reviews']),
                    'href'            => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id'])
                );
            }
        }


        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/featured.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/featured.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/module/featured.tpl';
        }

        $this->render();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must modify the model file of product at catalog/model/product.php  by adding `m.image AS manufacturer_img,` to the existing select query of getProduct function. See snippet below:

......................

```php
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, `m.image AS manufacturer_img,` (SELECT price ...
```

................

then add `'manufacturer_img'  => $query->row['manufacturer_img'],` to the return array:

.......................

```php
'manufacturer_id'  => $query->row['manufacturer_id'],
'manufacturer_img'  => $query->row['manufacturer_img'],
'manufacturer'     => $query->row['manufacturer'],
```

......................

Finally on the featured module `catalog/controller/module/featured.php` as you've did, you can add this snippet code to get manufacturer related data of the product:

............................

```php
'manufacturer'    => $product_info['manufacturer'], 
'manufacturer_id' => $product_info['manufacturer_id'],
'manufacturer_img'=> $product_info['manufacturer_img'],
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i will  modify as u recomended and will return with a feedback.

Comment: @AlbertO. If this solved Your problem, please accept this answer by clicking on the *tick* on the left side of this post. Accepting correct answers helps other users searching for the same/similar problem to identify the questions with accepted answers so that they can find solutions for their problem easier and more quickly. Optionally You may want to upvote the answer as well as it was nicely done. Consider this as a *thanks* for helping to solve Your problem.

Comment: your're welcome. I am very happy that it help you ^_^